# Do AWS support SES in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses

I'm trying to figure out how to automate the creation of several cloud resources in AWS, using CloudFormation.

Now I need to include the creation of SES (Simple Email Service) domain, but couldn't find the documentation, but I've already checked:

- [Simple Email Service Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-the-api.html)
- [CloudFormation Resource Types Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html)

Do AWS support SES in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not supported, but who knows Re:Invent 2017 is around the corner ,,,

[Question asked on AWS Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=219022)

It is possible by creating a custom function, some [blog](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/verify-domains-for-ses-using-cloudformation-8dd185c9b05c) about SES and cloudformation.

Comment: Even though it is possible to create node scripts to do whatever we want using AWS SDK, I would only use it if I have to create more than a hundred domains, not for 10. Let's see what comes out from re:Invent.

Answer (score 20):

CloudFormation provides several built-in [Amazon SES resource types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SES.html), but as of <s>2018</s> <s>2020</s> 2022 is still missing the ones many people need: **domain** and **email verification**.

**UPDATE:** Amazon finally added [`AWS::SES::EmailIdentity`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-emailidentity.html) (in mid-2022). The remainder of this answer is no longer necessary.

---

Earlier answer...

Fortunately, CloudFormation has the ability to define your own [custom resource types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). I've built `Custom::SES_Domain` and `Custom::SES_EmailIdentity` resources that are designed to play well with other CloudFormation resources. Get them here: https://github.com/medmunds/aws-cfn-ses-domain.

Once you've pulled the custom [`CfnSESResources`](https://github.com/medmunds/aws-cfn-ses-domain) into your template, you can verify an SES domain like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  # Provision a domain with Amazon SES:
  MySESDomain:
    Type: Custom::SES_Domain
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt CfnSESResources.Outputs.CustomDomainIdentityArn
      Domain: "example.com"
      EnableSend: true
      EnableReceive: false

  # Then add all required DNS records for SES verification and usage:
  MyRoute53RecordsForSES:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: "example.com."
      RecordSets: !GetAtt MySESDomain.Route53RecordSets
```

Full instructions are in the repository. `Custom::SES_Domain` has [properties](https://github.com/medmunds/aws-cfn-ses-domain#properties) for controlling several common SES domain options, and exposes [attributes](https://github.com/medmunds/aws-cfn-ses-domain#fngetatt) that feed into your CloudFormation DNS resources: either a standard `AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup` resource as shown above, or other (external) DNS providers via zone file entries.

Comment: AWS CloudFormation now supports the `EmailIdentity` resource. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-emailidentity.html

Answer (score 5):

CloudFormation provides a nativ [AWS::SES::EmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-emailidentity.html) resource now. (since  30.07.2022)

Here is an example with automated Route53 DEKIM setup/verification:

```yaml
EmailIdentity:
    Type: AWS::SES::EmailIdentity
    Properties: 
        EmailIdentity: {your.domain.com}

Route53DEKIM:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
    Properties:
        HostedZoneId: {ZoneId}
        RecordSets:
            -   Name: !GetAtt EmailIdentity.DkimDNSTokenName1
                Type: CNAME
                TTL: '3600'
                ResourceRecords:
                    - !GetAtt EmailIdentity.DkimDNSTokenValue1
            -   Name: !GetAtt EmailIdentity.DkimDNSTokenName2
                Type: CNAME
                TTL: '3600'
                ResourceRecords:
                    - !GetAtt EmailIdentity.DkimDNSTokenValue2
            -   Name: !GetAtt EmailIdentity.DkimDNSTokenName3
                Type: CNAME
                TTL: '3600'
                ResourceRecords:
                    - !GetAtt EmailIdentity.DkimDNSTokenValue3
```

`{your.domain.com}` and `{ZoneId}` must be adapted.

Answer (score 2):

Though AWS Cloudformation is not currently supported use the AWS SDKs ( e.g [Node SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html)) to provision the SES resources required.

Its a common practice to use custom code with AWS SDKs and AWS CLI commands in combination with CloudFormation to provision resources AWS since each approach can be advantages, based on the parameters, number of resources, repetitions and etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Update October 2022**

CloudFormation now supports the [AWS::SES::EmailIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-emailidentity.html) resource, which allows us to define both domains and email addresses through infrastructure as code.

According to the CloudFormation [release history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) this resource was added on June 30, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the current list of [SES Resource Types supported by CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SES.html):

> AWS::SES::ConfigurationSet
>
> AWS::SES::ConfigurationSetEventDestination
>
> AWS::SES::ReceiptFilter
>
> AWS::SES::ReceiptRule
>
> AWS::SES::ReceiptRuleSet
>
> AWS::SES::Template

Answer (score -3):

Not supported. But, you can make it handled by lambda.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: >-
  A simple email example
Resources:
  FunctionEmailHandler:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: email.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ..
      Description: >-
        ...
      Tags:
        App: your app
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10    
      Policies:
        - Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - 's3:GetObject'
              Resource: '*'

  LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !GetAtt FunctionEmailHandler.Arn
      Principal: ses.amazonaws.com

  SESEmailRecievedRule:
    Type: "AWS::SES::ReceiptRule"
    Properties:
      RuleSetName: your default rule set name
      After: store-email-to-s3
      Rule:
        Name: email-recieved-rule
        Enabled: true
        Actions:
          - LambdaAction:
              FunctionArn: !GetAtt FunctionEmailHandler.Arn
              InvocationType: Event
```

Comment: the question was about how to create a **SES domain** using CloudFormation and not how to handle email reception using lambda