# Does AWS Cloud Formation supports SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ses

I'm working on CloudFormation and I couldn't find any documentation/resources/sample CF templates for SES.

I know AWS didn't support CF for SES before. By any chance do they now (after re:Invent 17) or any useful resources that might help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do AWS support SES in CloudFormation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47026560/do-aws-support-ses-in-cloudformation)

Answer (score 2):

There is a handful of SES resources supported. For example [AWS::SES::ConfigurationSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-configurationset.html).

There is always the ability to use [custom resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for any case where there is not an official resource.

Comment: Thank you. Even though this could be achievable via custom resources, I feel it's too much of a work to get something very little done.  I'd wait for AWS to support SES

Comment: One significant missing case is verifying and configuring your email domain (managing SES domain identities). Googling will turn up a few, unofficial custom resources to handle this, including one I wrote: [`Custom::SES_Domain`](https://github.com/medmunds/aws-cfn-ses-domain). (But yeah, sure wish AWS had this built in.)